# JSON server doesn't accept JSON file, authentication_failed

Tags: json

I'm trying to send a JSON file to a server but the remote server doesn't accept the authentication.

The UserID and Password are inside the JSON file. I got he same answer with CURL and with my .NET desktop application.

I sniffed the connection and saw a **Client HELLO** and **HTTP/1.1 100 Continue** then the JSON file, so it seems to be OK.

The pass and user are fine, I checked with the remote provider.

What could be happening? What else should I test/check?

Comment: The protocol actually dictates that the authentication info be inside the file and not the authentication headers?

Comment: @sinanspd They sent me a PDF and an JSON file as example, I changed the UserId and Password in the JSON file and sent it using CURL and get the same result as I got in my .NET app.(WinForm) How I can send the credentials outside the JSON file?